# Can I save-for-web an artboard "as-screen" instead of pixel preview in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

I'm using Illustrator for painting (no printing) and using a lot of raster effects (mostly blur). I am also using the effects for masking as well.

The thing is that the raster effects look fine on normal preview, but on pixel preview (and when saved for web), the effects look very degraded. It seems it only happens when the effect is masked, and look worse when masked multiple times through multiple layer trees, which is essential for my work. So, that is the context why I am asking.

So, I would like to know if I can save-for-web (PNG) the file that looks exactly like how the image is at x1 zoom on Illustator without pixel preview turned on, instead of how it looks on pixel preview.

The file was created as web preset and set to RGB.

Comment: Well a PNG **is** a pixel-based image.. so pixel preview is showing you how things look for a pixel based image. I'm afraid showing a couple sample images (or just cropped parts) of what you are referring to will help. What is your Document Raster Effects Settings set to?

Comment: The raster is set to 72dpi and made no difference as I tested it with other dpi. Please refer to this link: https://imgur.com/bln57Ld . It is a part of an image that I am having issues with. I cannot show without-pixel-preview for comparison as I cannot currently reach my PC but I guess it should be enough. As you can see in the image, the gradation from blur effects is not smooth like it should show on normal preview, with the upper gray part sticking out especially. The image is masked with 000000 and FFFFFF shapes and the issue gets worse with more visible boundaries with more mask layers.

Comment: I'm afraid vector tools in general simply aren't great at supporting a bunch of pixel-based blurs and subtle masks. The translation to pixels is, well, what it is. Pixel preview *is* showing you the best it can do. You *may* have better luck copy/pasting to a raster editor like Photoshop, then saving from that app.